# Appending DataFrame to Create a Archived Database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a script to process my customer orders, every time I run it, it fetches data from an Excel spreadsheet, and it generates a DataFrame df1, with similar labels but different number of rows and different values (each row is a new order).

From there, I can process the orders as I need.

Next, I am trying to append together each iteration of the df1 in a csv ('merged_orders_static.csv'), which in essence, will be a database of archived orders.

I tried different for loop combinations, initiating an empty lists, using context manager, but every time it overwrites the previous iteration instead of appending to it.

My latest attempt:

```
archive = []



with open('merged_orders_static.csv') as my_file:
    new_file = pd.read_csv(my_file).set_index("Order Date").append(df1)
    for i in new_file:
        archive = new_file.append(df1)

print(archive)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try following:

```
with open('merged_orders_static.csv') as my_file:
    my_file = pd.read_csv(my_file).set_index("Order Date")
df1=df1.set_index("Order Date")
new_file = my_file.append(df1)
new_file.to_csv(merged_orders_static.csv')
```

`new_file` dataframe will have the entire data appended to it.

Comment: This appends df1 to my_file, which I already managed to do. Every time I run the script, I am trying to get the new value stored in df1 appended to my_file.

Comment: I have updated the code. The problem is you are not writing back to the file.